# Why is threading.Timer a function and not a class?

Tags: python-2.7

I was hoping to subclass threading.Timer, but get a error even in the most trivial cases.

```
class MyDelayedEvent(threading.Timer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyDelayedEvent, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Which gives the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    function() argument 1 must be code, not str
```

Weird, but a little poking I see that the object is actually `threading._Timer` and in the python 2.7 source the definition of Timer is as follows

```
def Timer(*args, **kwargs):
    return _Timer(*args, **kwargs)

class _Timer(Thread):
    """Call a function after a specified number of seconds:
    ...
```

(**https://svn.python.org/projects/python/tags/r27a1/Lib/threading.py**)

Why would python 2.7 bother creating a function that just returns a constructed object? What is the point of _Timer here? Is it safe to subclass _Timer?

Comment: It's a factory function, and in Python 3, gone, replaced by the actual class.

Comment: They may have wanted to allow the opportunity to change what class the factory function created an instance of, without requiring callers to change what they were calling. Maybe while they were still playing around with different implementations or something?